# Dart - Convert json to a typed list

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a recipes app and I have an endpoint that returns all the data and an array with all the ingredients needed.
In my provider I fetch all the recipes with Recipes.fromJson and everything works fine, but I have some problems when need to fetch the ingredients array.

This is the ingredient json ( as part of a bigger json with all the recipes informations):

```
[{quantity: 1, unit: , ingredient: rortolo di pasta sfoglia rettangolare, notes: }, {quantity: 2, unit: , ingredient: patate, notes: ( o 1 o 3 dipende dalla grandezza delle patate)}, {quantity: qb, unit: , ingredient: pesto fresco, notes: potete farlo o comprarlo l'importante è che sia quello fresco}, {quantity: qb, unit: , ingredient: formaggio a scelta, notes: io ho usato emmental, evitate di scegliere formggi troppo molli farebbero solo poltiglia}, {quantity: 1, unit: , ingredient: tuorlo d'uovo, notes: }]
```

Ingredient:

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class Ingredient {
  final String quantity;
  final String unit;
  final String ingredient;
  final String note;

  Ingredient({
    @required this.quantity,
    @required this.ingredient,
    this.unit,
    this.note,
  });

  factory Ingredient.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Ingredient(
      ingredient: json['ingredient'] ?? '',
      quantity: json['quantity'] ?? '',
      unit: json['unit'] ?? '',
      note: json['note'] ?? null,
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the `Recipe.fromJson`, in a Recipe model, where I try to fetch the ingredients and build a List with no success.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

import '../models/ingredient.dart';

class Recipe {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String intro;
  final String difficulty;
  final String cookingTime;
  final String featureImage;
  final String description;
  final String servings;
  final List<Ingredient> ingredients;

  Recipe({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.difficulty,
    @required this.cookingTime,
    @required this.featureImage,
    @required this.description,
    @required this.ingredients,
    @required this.servings,
    this.intro,
  });

  factory Recipe.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var recipeIngredients = json['ingredients'];
    List<Ingredient> ingredients = recipeIngredients.map((i) {
      print(i);
      return Ingredient.fromJson(i);
    }).toList();

    return Recipe(
      id: json['id'] ?? null,
      title: json['title'] ?? '',
      difficulty: json['difficulty'] ?? 'facile',
      cookingTime: json['cooking_time'] ?? '',
      servings: json['servings'] ?? '',
      featureImage:
          json['featureImage'] ?? 'https://via.placeholder.com/1920x768',
      description: json['description'] ?? '',
      intro: json['intro'] ?? '',
      ingredients: ingredients,
    );
  }
}
```

*NB: if I print `recipeIngredients` I get the json posted above.*

If I run the code I get this error:

> flutter: type 'List' is not a subtype of type
> 'List'

Any idea why?

EDIT:
This is what I get from the API:

```
[
   {
      "id":348,
      "title":"Spiedini di mazzancolle cocco e lime",
      "intro":"Oggi voglio proporvi una ricetta semplicissima da fare e da inserire in un buffet di antipasti. E' molto molto gustosa, dal sapore tropicale e conquister\u00e0 tutti i palati per la sua particolarit\u00e0 e il perfetto connubio tra gli ingredienti presenti nella ricetta.\r\n\r\nDai andiamo in cucina insieme vedrete che non resterete delusi",
      "featureImage":"https:\/\/example.it\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/12\/coccolime.jpeg",
      "difficulty":"Easy",
      "cooking_time":"30",
      "servings":"4",
      "ingredients":[
         {
            "quantity":"400",
            "unit":"g",
            "ingredient":"mazzancolle",
            "notes":"o se preferite gamberi"
         },
         {
            "quantity":"4 cucchiai",
            "unit":"",
            "ingredient":"farina di cocco",
            "notes":"(non cocco rap\u00e8 farina di cocco)"
         },
         {
            "quantity":"2 cucchiai ",
            "unit":"",
            "ingredient":"pangrattato",
            "notes":""
         },
         {
            "quantity":"1",
            "unit":"",
            "ingredient":"lime",
            "notes":""
         },
         {
            "quantity":"qb",
            "unit":"",
            "ingredient":"pepe rosa in grani da macinare al momento",
            "notes":""
         },
         {
            "quantity":"",
            "unit":"",
            "ingredient":"",
            "notes":""
         }
      ],
      "instructions":[
         {
            "image":"",
            "description":"La realizzazione di questa ricetta \u00e8 davvero molto semplice. Come prima cosa preriscaldate il forno a 180 gradi , preparate in un piatto il mix di farina di cocco, pepe rosa macinato al momento ( io uso un pepe rosa con macinino nel tappo che contiene pepe rosa e limone e d\u00e0 un tocco davvero molto speciale) e pan grattato, preparate anche un altro piatto con dentro il succo di un lime e pulite i gamberi togliendo il carapace "
         },
         {
            "image":"",
            "description":"Immergete adesso le mazzancolle nel piatto con il mix di farina di cocco,pan grattato e pepe rosa e girateli per bene in modo da infarinare tutte le mazzancolle"
         },
         {
            "image":"",
            "description":"Adesso immergeteli nel piatto col succo di lime e girateli velocemente per far prendere il succo a tutte le mazzancolle"
         },
         {
            "image":"",
            "description":"A questo punto rimetteteli nel piatto col mix di farina di cocco,pepe rosa e pan grattato e girateli di nuovo per far prendere la farina a tutte le mazzancolle"
         },
         {
            "image":"",
            "description":"Mettetele in un piatto e fateli riposare 5 minuti"
         },
         {
            "image":"",
            "description":"Adesso prendete gli spiedini e mettete 3 mazzancolle su ogni spiedino"
         },
         {
            "image":"",
            "description":"Prendete la teglia da forno coperta con carta da forno, disponete sopra gli spiedini e infornate a 180 gradi per 15 minuti"
         },
         {
            "image":"349",
            "description":"Sfornate, mettete su un piatto da portata e servite"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: You do *not* need to write `fromJson` manually. Instead, use `json_serializable` package, which will **auto** generate that.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that package, I will try it asap

Comment: That package handles many details quite well, such as the problem you meet. Actually, that will automatically generate mostly the same code you have written in your fromJson.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, I will try it in a new branch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61583933/345812

All I need to do is:

```
List<Ingredient> ingredients = List<Ingredient>.from(
        recipeIngredients.map((x) => Ingredient.fromJson(x)));
```

This will return the correct list

Comment: You do not need to write fromJson manually. Instead, use json_serializable package, which will auto generate that.

Answer (score 0):

(This is not a *direct* answer to the question; however, the question seems to be a A-B problem so this answer may help.)

You do *not* need to write `fromJson` manually. Instead, use `json_serializable` package, which will **auto** generate that.

That package handles many details quite well, such as the problem you meet. Actually, that will automatically generate mostly the same code you have written in your fromJson.